# Pythonic way of counting number of elements processed in loop

Tags: python, loops

Using `enumerate` works for values greater than `0`, but breaks at `0`:

```
>>> def process_data(elements):
...     for cnt, value in enumerate(range(elements)):
...         pass
...     print(f'Processed {cnt + 1} elements')
... 
>>> process_data(3)
Processed 3 elements
>>> process_data(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in process_data
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cnt' referenced before assignment
```

Is there a better, pythonic way, to count how many entries are processed in the loop?

This is doable of course, but then why use `enumerate` at all:

```
>>> def process_data(elements):
...     processed = -1
...     for cnt, value in enumerate(range(elements)):
...         processed = cnt
...     print(f'Processed {processed + 1} elements')
... 
>>> process_data(3)
Processed 3 elements
>>> process_data(0)
Processed 0 elements
```

Comment: In this particular case, what is even the point of counting if you have the number as an input? `elements` would always be the answer. In other cases `len` would do the job and when neither are suitable, `enumerate` or counter are both valid approaches.

Comment: @go2nirvana This is just an example. Normally I do not know how many entries are processed in the loop (generator). My real code is not the `process_data` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just give the index variable an initial value before the `enumerate` loop

```
count = 0
for count, obj in enumerate(objects, start=1):
    pass
print(f'Processed {count} elements')
```

You can pass an initial value to `enumerate` to start at `1` rather than adding `1` to the count afterwards

Comment: Ok, this looks interesting and succinct. The only worry is that reading that code will always force me to wonder "why is the counter set to 0 outside the loop"? Once you think about it, it's obvious. But you have to think about it - it's not *natural*.

Comment: @blueFast that is actually a pretty common pattern, it shouldn't cause any confusion. And often it is OK to think about things, haha. Sometimes, code has to be complex and takes time to grasp which is totally fine.

Comment: @blueFast add comments to your code if you think the intention or reason is not clear. I would argue that there is nothing _natural_ about programming

Answer (score 2):

Why not this?

```
def process_data(elements):
    processed = 0
    for processed, value in enumerate(range(elements), start=1):
        # do something
    print(f'Processed {processed} elements')
```

Comment: `processed` will be 1 less than the actual number of elements here?